# C++ compiler can't find a file

Tags: c++, file, io

I've been working for quite a while on this, but can't seem to get why the files sample_uc_students.txt and sample_smc_grads.txt are not being read. They're premade documents I put into my documents folder but they're not opening.

```
Student* readStudentsFromFile(string filename, int num) {
ifstream studentsStream;
studentsStream.open(filename.c_str());
if (!studentsStream.is_open()) {
    cerr << "Couldn't open the file " << filename << endl;
    return NULL;
}
// create a new array of students with size 'num'
Student* students = new Student[num];
string name, school, sid;
int id;
// read student records from file
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    getline(studentsStream, name, ',');
    getline(studentsStream, sid, ',');
    getline(studentsStream, school);
    istringstream idConv(sid);
    idConv >> id;
    // create a student object from the record and store it in the array
    students[i] = Student(id, name, school);
}
studentsStream.close();
return students;
}

int main() {

const int SIZE = 10;
const int SMC_SIZE = 5;
const int SMC_UC_GRADS_SIZE = 2;
Student* uc = readStudentsFromFile("sample_uc_students.txt", UC_SIZE);
Student* smc = readStudentsFromFile("sample_smc_grads.txt", SMC_SIZE);

\Time it will take
time_t start, end;

time(&start);
Student* common1 = findCommonStudents1(uc, UC_SIZE, smc, SMC_SIZE,
                                       SMC_UC_GRADS_SIZE);
time(&end);
cout << "Using linear search it took " << difftime(end, start) << " seconds."
<< endl;

/*
 * library sort function to sort an array: sort(arr, arr+size)
 * Note that values must be comparable with the < operator
 */ 


sort(common1, common1 + SMC_UC_GRADS_SIZE);
writeStudentsToFile(common1, SMC_UC_GRADS_SIZE, "smc_grads_at_uc_1.txt");

time(&start);
Student* common2 = findCommonStudents2(uc, UC_SIZE, smc, SMC_SIZE,
                                       SMC_UC_GRADS_SIZE);
time(&end);
cout << "Using binary search it took " << difftime(end, start)
<< " seconds." << endl;

sort(common2, common2 + SMC_UC_GRADS_SIZE);
writeStudentsToFile(common2, SMC_UC_GRADS_SIZE, "smc_grads_at_uc_2.txt");

delete[] smc;
delete[] uc;
delete[] common1;
delete[] common2;
return 0;

}
```

Any suggestions on how to get these to open or perhaps I should try to open them through a path?

Comment: Are you running your program from your documents directory?

Comment: For future reference, you might be able to get better error information from `strerror()` in `<stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use:

```
Student* uc = readStudentsFromFile("sample_uc_students.txt", UC_SIZE);
```

the program expects the file "sample_uc_students.txt" to be in the same directory where the program is run. It's not going to look for the file in your Documents folder.

Your options:

1. Copy the files to the directory from where the program is run.
2. Use absolute path of the files instead of using just the file name.

Comment: Thank you, but how could I find that directory, or change the directory that my program runs in?

Comment: The directory where the program is run?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to figure out where I can find where the program is run, I just drag the documents into that directory correct?

Comment: That is correct. The directory where the program is run depends on your development environment. If you are using Visual Studio, you can lookup that value by going into the "Properties" of the target from the Solutions Explorer. If you use a different development environment, you will have to find the run directory by yourself or get help from somebody.